# I need to send only first tab of rendered excel via mail subscription in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created report with multiple tabs when exported to excel. In Mail subscription, I need to send only first page of my rendered excel of report.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS 2008 R2 or later you can use the Globals!RenderFormat.Name

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL")
```

If you are using SSRS 2008 or earlier, this is not available. the only way I can think of doing it is to add a parameter to the report that you can then use to hide the relevant sections. You could then set this parameter as default = false but force it to be true for your subscription.